# import cv2 terminal error - python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib, command-line

I'm trying to simply install and use cv2, numpy and matplotlib. 
All installed successfully but when I type into the terminal "import ..." it gives me the following error?

I'm confused because what the terminal is suggesting, I've already installed it that way?

I'm not sure about why it's pointing me to the packages either?

```
import cv2
The program 'import' can be found in the following packages:
 * imagemagick
 * graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Thanks

Comment: have you restarted the terminal after installation?

Comment: opencv needs additional packages to create windows, and in this case it is suggesting that you install those packages.

Answer (score 0):

`import` is a command from `imagemagick` and `graphicsmagick`, you are trying to import a module python in you terminal, but, you should import in python shell:

```
$ python
Python 3.6.3 (default, Oct  9 2017, 12:11:29) 
[GCC 7.2.1 20170915 (Red Hat 7.2.1-2)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> code_here
>>> exit()
```

OVERVIEW from import from imagemagick.

```
   The `import` program is a member of the ImageMagick(1) suite of tools.  Use it to capture some or all of an X server screen and save the image  to  a
   file.

   For  more  information  about the import command, point your browser to file:///usr/share/doc/ImageMagick-6/www/import.html or http://www.imagemag‐
   ick.org/script/import.php.
```